# Проверка функций в Си

Tags: c, функции, проверка

В языке Си я почти каждую функцию проверяю на возвращаемое значение, правильно ли я поступаю? Если речь идет даже о таких функциях, как printf или fclose

Comment: Обе функции могут как успешно отработать так и неуспешно. По-хорошему - правильно. это больше относится к тому насколько надёжная программа вам нужна, и как именно вы будете обрабатывать неуспешный результат.

Comment: Проверять надо всё, что может вернуть ошибку. Некоторые ленятся, и это плохо

Comment: @andreymal, только не всегда понятно, что с этой ошибкой делать...

Comment: Лучше громко и явно завершить программу с сообщением об ошибке, чем получить на каком-то этапе код ошибки вместо ожидаемого результата, и продолжить выполнение, не заметив этого.

Answer (score 1):

Для лучшего понимания, конечно, **стоит**, это поможет вам избежать ошибок и внесет ясность. Особенно, если вы новичок

Answer (score 1):

В C проверка значений функций является стандартной практикой, поскольку средства, существующие в таких языках как C++, Java, C#, а именно *обработка исключений*, в C недоступны.

Тем не менее, в C есть возможность возвращать управления из функций большой вложенности без промежуточных проверок с помощью так называемых *длинных переходов*. Ищите описания функций `setjmp` и `longjmp`, они как раз и помогают организовать *длинные переходы*.

Проверять возвращаемые значения таких функций, как `printf` большого смысла нет. Ошибку в строке формата можно проверить непосредственно, или с помощью таких средств, как **lint**, и если её там нет, `printf` будет возвращать предсказуемые значения.

Если же вдруг по каким-то причинам `printf` вернёт что-то некорректное, это будет означать, что с вашей системой что-то глубоко не так, и вряд ли вы даже сможете напечатать разумное сообщение об ошибке.

Поэтому — корректный C-way это проверять возвращаемые значения, особенно, у таких функций, как `fopen` или `malloc`, но без фанатизма, и используя в некоторых случаях *длинные переходы* вместо большого количества вложенных проверок.

Answer (score 1):

Обычно проверяют значения, которые вводит пользователь или программа читает из внешних источников (валидация). А необходимость проверки результатов функций - зависит от вашей задумки. Разумеется каждая  проверка - это дополнительное время выполнения и программный код, что может быть критично, например при разработке под Микроконтроллеры. Но всегда проводите проверки, когда результат функции критичен для дальнейшей работы программы - это увеличивает надежность и предсказуемость.

Если это функция стандартной библиотеки и она может возвращать ошибку - то ее лучше тоже обработать (что часто не делают в примерах). Можно вести лог ошибок или сообщить об этом пользователю (например, в stderr), либо отреагировать изменением хода программы (повторная попытка записи/получения и т.д. - но избегайте зацикливаний, если ни когда не получите удачный ответ).

Любое сообщение об ошибках в ходе выполнения - будет полезно при отладке.
И в целом это хороший тон - но всегда думайте головой.

Answer (score 0):

Проверка **каждой** функции - это, конечно, плохо (*)
Также не проверять абсолютно все функции - тоже плохо (**)

(*) 
Каждый раз, присваивая значение функции, вы теряете в производительности капельку времени.
Но если таких операций много, а время сильно ограничено....

(**)
Если произойдет ошибка - будет крайне затруднительно её найти

Answer (score 0):

Стоит проверять, или - нет, зависит от того, чьё время Вы цените больше:

1. Если Вы больше цените своё время - проверяйте
2. Если более ценно время процессора - не проверяйте.